# Host java web application into Windows IIS server

Tags: java, iis

Can i put my java web application into Windows IIS server .Now its working fine under Tomcat 6 server .But i want to put it in IIS server .Is it possible ..If yes pls let me know whats the Procedure ......

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to do that is to keep your app on Tomcat and use JK ISAPI redirector plugin. [Take a look at this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html).

Comment: Hii but on my main machine only have one server iis no tomcat..

Comment: I'm sure that you can run Tomcat and IIS on the same server.  Just make sure that they use different port numbers.

Comment: In general it does not matter where you have your Tomcat, but you will need one anyway. You will have to install it (on the same server or any other server) and configure JK ISAPI plugin

Comment: The ISAPI is not the only way, as you can also use IIS 7 and above native connector from BonCode, http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/.

Answer (score 3):

IIS is a web server (more or less) and Tomcat is Java application server. You can't serve Java app directly from within IIS. IIS can be used as proxy to Tomcat server but you can't run your Java app without it (or any other equivalent).