# Can Java EE web applications be hosted on IIS

Tags: java, iis

Can we host a Java EE web application on IIS 5.1 server on windows XP?

Comment: What's different than this other question of yours? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155691/host-java-web-application-into-windows-iis-server

Answer (score 2):

You can forward your requests from IIS to another local tomcat or other java application server.

Comment: So its not possible to host in iis??

when  and why we forward the request as we have the server running why cant we directly call it???

Comment: IIS is a web server. To run a java application you need a java application server like Tomcat. You can forward your requests from IIS to the Tomcat server but you might just want to dump IIS and use Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your Application Server into the same machine as the IIS server. Then use [AJP](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) to connect IIS to your Java APPServer.

But I don't think you will be able to run Java Applications directly from IIS only.

Answer (score 0):

IIS can never Java web-applications directly. But with a plugin we can do it..

You can refer [this page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/how-does-jsp-work-on-iis)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Java EE cannot be hosted in IIS. To host Java EE Application you need at least Servlet container or a full Java EE container which is not supported by IIS. Although, some plugin might be able to do so.

As for your reference, below link is Java EE compatibility by oracle:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely you can. If you need further info you'll have to provide more info about the type of Java application you wish to use, and the version of IIS.

Comment: its a j2ee project , and iis version is 5.1 on windows xp