# Run JasperReports Server in IIS

Tags: java, iis, jasperserver

By default, *JasperReports Server* run in *Apache Tomcat*.
 
However, I have IIS server and want *JasperReports Server* to run in it.
Any idea?

Comment: Are you talking about JR Server?

Comment: Yes. Can JR Server run with IIS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256084/running-a-java-web-application-in-iis & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157715/hosting-java-web-appliction-on-iis

Comment: Definitely looks like a dup of those to me.

Answer (score 0):

Always you call JasperReports as an external application, if it's not too often.

[This might give you a clue](http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/pdf-doc-xls-odf-from-php)